# Redirect calls to move/copy inside a batch file to own application

Tags: redirect, batch-file

I have a complicated batch file (under windows), let's call it BigMess.bat. It makes a lot of actions that I would like to monitor (especially the copy/move actions). I wouldn't like to touch the BigMess.bat.

Is it possible to redirect the calls to move/copy to my own application or another batch file?

I tried putting a move.bat file beside the BigMess.bat but it prefers the shell's move. Is it feasible *without* touching BigMess.bat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you run `BigMess.bat` with `cmd.exe` - no chance. as stated in [The Windows NT Command Shell - Command Search Sequence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120):

> If the command name [eg. `move`, `copy`] does not specify a path, the shell attempts to match the command name against the list of internal shell commands. If a match is found, the internal command executes.

it might be possible by using [another shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772/cmd-exe-replacement). have a look at [Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/). it has a) cmd.exe compatibilty, and b) [aliases](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?aliases.htm). aliases are [expanded before internal commands](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?parsing.htm), so you could use one like

```
alias copy=C:\path\to\your\monitor\app
```

good luck!