# Windows CMD Keyword Highlighting

Tags: colors, cmd, console2

Is it possible to change the color of keywords in the windows cmd.exe? I would like commands like "ls, cd, pwd, etc." to be different colors.

Also, I've tried "COLOR 1D" using the list that comes from running "color /?", but this just colors all of the text. I'm looking for something that just colors command line keywords.

I have extensions like Console2 and Clink; but I don't think they have such features.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [CMD.exe replacement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19772)

Comment: Thanks. ConEmu or Console is not what I'm looking for but PSReadLine is; to get it though, I need to use PsGet which uses Powershell 4.0. I tried to download "Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all but it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: I am interested in this, I'll do quick search and write back! This one might get you somewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line